# How to get value from numpy array with dynamic steps?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

So i have numpy array like this

`x = [1,2,3,4,5]`

if i want to get this

`x = [1,2,4]`

how to produce this result?
I understand the i:j:k syntax but it only have one step but what i want to achieve is dynamic step

Comment: `x[[0, 1, 3]]` will do it.

Comment: what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Okay this works, never think about this because i thought that it's not possible. Is there any explanation or that's just how it works? @WarrenWeckesser

Comment: See https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays and https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Turns out i read the wrong docs all this time @WarrenWeckesser